# Custom Validation on Knowledge Articles

Tags: validation, knowledge

I want to add some custom validation on articles. The problem is that articles don't support validation rules([idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZMC9AAO)) nor do they allow triggers([idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jVKGAA2)). You can do Process Builder or workflows, but those don't let you perform data validation and display errors to the user. I tried creating an invocable action in Apex that throws an exception and calling that from process builder, but it displays an ugly error to the user that is not helpful at all.